# components overlapping on each other

Tags: android

Since, i am new to android, i was trying to build a scientific calculator . So in that i have an `edit text` which displays the results of the calculations.

Now what i was doing was to provide a button on top of it , so that , people can access the advance features of the calculator.

I read various questions regarding and tried to do that and it doesn't seem to work.

Like obviously they overlap.

But `edittext` comes up on top of `imagebutton` which makes any click event on `imagebutton` useless.

**Code**

```
<ImageButton
        android:contentDescription="View advance features"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/go_advance"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="@id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@id/linearLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"

        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:height="225dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="end|bottom"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="104dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="207dp" />
```

[image]

How would i put my `imagebutton` on top of `edittext`?

Comment: I don't see the need for a LinearLayout. And instead of a RelativeLayout I'd use a GridLayout, which seems the perfect container for this UI.

Comment: `relative>linear(edit text+grid layout),image button`  This is the real structure

Comment: i get it , what you are trying to say, Thank you @BernoulliGate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using RelativeLayout as parent layout. Place your ImageButton after LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
        ...
        edit text, buttons etc
        ...
   </LinearLayout>
   <ImageButton/>
</RelativeLayout>
```